# logback xml configuration for web application

Tags: java, xml, logging, configuration, logback

I am using logback SLF4J for logging the debug/error statements. Could you please let me know how to use single logback.xml configuration file for multiple environments (dev/qa/prod)? Right now, i am editing xml file for each environment to specify dbname...I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why is dbname in your logback.xml?

Comment: @FGreg Most likely explanation is the use of a db appender, and different DB urls dependent on dev/test/prod

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options (most of them documented [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html))

1. Use properties in the log configuration which are set externally (either java properties or OS environment variables)
2. Use JNDI settings (creating db datasources is pretty common)
3. Generate a logback.xml file as part of the deployment process
4. [JMX configurator](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/jmxConfig.html) which allows you to reload the configuration from a named file
5. Package a WAR file for each environment (don't really recommend this included for completeness)